# iOS 8 Today Extension: Is it possible to add editable text field?

Tags: ios, widget, textfield, ios8, ios-app-extension

I am trying to create a simple Today Extension. I was able to add a label wherein the value can be updated via the main app. Now, I am exploring the possibility to update the value in main app via the extension. However, when I tried to add a textfield, I cannot input anything.

Is this a limitation of the extension? If not, can you please guide me how to accomplish this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is a limitation.

It says in Apple's extension programming guide:

> Because user interaction with Today widgets is quick and limited, you should design a simple, streamlined UI that highlights the information users are interested in. In general, it’s a good idea to limit the number of interactive items in a widget. In particular, note that iOS widgets don’t support keyboard entry.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Today.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH11-SW1

Comment: i know apple not suggestion use textfield,but this damn guy should have a way to do that,wired, wired....

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/%E6%AC%A7%E8%B7%AF%E8%8B%B1%E8%AF%AD%E8%AF%8D%E5%85%B8-eudic/id367278030?mt=8

 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLnEM.png